# How to handle dynamic image paths with webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I've managed to process the majority of my icons within a large application but there are still two use cases which don't get caught.

- Dynamic paths used within angular templates
  `<md-icon md-svg-src="{{'/assets/icons/ic-' + $ctrl.icon + '.svg'}}"></md-icon>`
- Paths used as varibled within components that are passed to angular templates

i.e something along the lines of

```
class Comp {
   this.settingsLinks = [
     {name: 'advanced settings', icon: '/assets/icons/ic-settings.svg'}
   ]
}
```

and then that gets used within a template like so

```
<div ng-repeat="setting in $ctrl.settingsLinks">
  <md-icon md-svg-src="{{setting.icon}}"></md-icon>
</div>
```

My webpack config is like so

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loaders: 'html-loader',
        options: {
          attrs: ['md-icon:md-svg-src', 'img:ng-src'],
          root: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
          name: '[name]-[hash].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        enforce: 'pre'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name() {
            return '[name]-[hash].[ext]';
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: [
          'ng-annotate-loader',
          'babel-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: conf.path.src('index.html')
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('index-[contenthash].css'),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), conf.paths.dist),
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js'
  },
  entry: {
    app: [`./${conf.path.src('app/app.module.js')}`],
    vendor: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies)
  },
};
```

I've been looking at the `webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin` as a potential way of handling the dynamic paths does anyone have any insight into what I'm trying to achieve? I want to be able to hash names for cache busting purposes but am struggling to work out how to handle dynamic paths in both js and templates.

Comment: Think you can make use of const `require.context('./base/path/to/img/holders', true);`
The second parameter (TRUE) is to consider subdirectories. You can use a third one to specify regex to search for them.
You can access their documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-context)

Comment: where would i add this code? instead of the dynamic path?

Comment: Are you able to create a index.js file to start the code up and add it as an entry file?
Might find a lot regarding with vue.js but some people seems to go for what you are looking for (from what I understood). Please correct me if I misunderstood. Think [this code](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/dynamically-register-files-from-a-folder-with-webpack-require-context/36581) example might help you further than I will! :x

Comment: so from my understanding that imports in all the possible icons (in this case) so that webpack knows what could be used there? does this have an effect on bundle size or is it entirely webpack based so it can infer what icons could go there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/

webpack gives access to `require.context` which allows telling webpack what the dynamic path could/should be, it removed the uncertainty of what is being required and allows you to return the newly hashed icon name from its original name. It does not require them all having an import cost it merely creates a map between the old and new name if I have understood correctly.

for example, this is saying grab all the file names in the icons folder grab the ones starting with ic- as that's our naming scheme for icons, this creates an object at build time I believe of all the possible icons to be used.

`const ICONS = require.context('../../../assets/icons', true, /ic-[a-zA-Z0-9.-]/);`

whats returned is a function where you can pass the original icon name and get back the hashed version. You can also use `ICONS.keys()` to get an array of icons.

here is an example usage I've used to provide some icons.

```
const ICONS = require.context('../../../assets/icons', true, /ic-[a-zA-Z0-9.-]/);

export function getIconFromPath(path) {
  return ICONS(path);
}

function getIconsFromPaths(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => Object.assign(obj, {[key]: ICONS(obj[key])}));
  return obj;
}

export default getIconsFromPaths({
  ARCHIVED: './ic-status-warning.svg',
  CANCELLED: './ic-status-cancelled.svg',
  CONFLICT: './ic-status-warning.svg',
  DRAFT: './ic-status-draft.svg',
  EARLIER: './ic-status-published.svg',
  ENDED: './ic-status-ended.svg',
  ERROR: './ic-status-published-failure.svg',
  FAILURE: './ic-status-failure.svg',
  INVALID: './ic-status-warning.svg',
  IN_PROGRESS: './ic-content-publish-in-progress.svg',
  LATEST: './ic-status-published-latest.svg',
  LOCKED: './ic-status-locked.svg',
  PUBLISHED: './ic-status-published.svg',
  PUBLISHING: './ic-content-publish-in-progress.svg',
  SCHEDULED: './ic-status-scheduled.svg',
  SCHEDULING: './ic-content-publish-in-progress.svg',
  UNLOCKED: './ic-status-unlocked.svg',
  UPDATED: './ic-webhook-request-success.svg',
  UNPUBLISHING: './ic-content-publish-in-progress.svg',
  UNSCHEDULING: './ic-content-publish-in-progress.svg',
  VALID: './ic-content-valid-tick.svg',
  WARNING: './ic-status-warning.svg'
});
```

Because webpack now knows what could be returned from here it can now hash the name and you can do all sorts of good stuff like optimizing at build time.

so the example class given in my question would be resolved by

```
import { getIconFromPath } from '../icons/;

class Comp {
   this.settingsLinks = [
     {
       name: 'advanced settings',
       icon: getIconFromPath('./ic-settings.svg')
     }
   ]
}
```